# Why can't Anakin Skywalker master both the way of the Jedi and Dark Side?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force

Anakin started off as a Jedi and then migrate over to the Dark Side. Why can't he be a master of both and become the greatest practitioner of the Force?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The Jedi and the Sith both use the same Force.** Using the force requires the same skills and sensitivity, regardless of whether you adhere to the dark or light sides. **In terms of raw force affinity, a light-sider doesn't have any capabilities that a dark-sider doesn't, and vice-versa.**

So, if there's no difference in ability, why are light side and dark side they separate? Well, because the dark and light sides are different philosophies and sets of values. A light-side force user will act differently to a dark-side one, not because the light-sider and dark-sider have inherently different force capabilities, but because they have different values and so pursue different ends by different means. Because the two philosophies are opposed in multiple respects, **it is impossible for a single individual to adhere to both the light-side and dark-side philosophies simultaneously.** (I guess technically someone could come up with a "grey side" hybrid philosophy with features of both, but that would be a new thing rather than light-side or dark-side. Reformed Orthodox Jedi-ism, perhaps.)

That said, some force techniques have been described as "light-side" or "dark-side" techniques. This indicates that these techniques either require belief in and self-identification with aspects of one of the two philosophies ("Force lighting torture *is* justifiable self-defence!"). As a consequence, **using a dark-side technique requires a force user to adhere to and believe in the dark side's ideals and ethics, at least in part; The same is true for light-side techniques and believing in light-side philosophy.**

tl;dr: **Mastering both the dark side and light side is meaningless because A) They're not separate or complimentary skillsets in the first place, and B) You can't *want* to use both at the same time.**

Comment: There is indeed a *grey side*. IIRC, there's a case in the EU of a Jedi that learnt Sith techniques but didn't use them for evil. Or something of that kind. Anyway, I don't think there's any case of a grey Jedi in the Disney Canon.

Comment: Love the *"Reformed Orthodox Jedi-ism"* +1

Comment: Sorry, this answer is canonically wrong. They differ in how they access the Force, not just in abstract intentions.

Comment: @DVK How so? They both use midichlorians, just one intends to use the Force to meet their ends while the other asks nicely.

Comment: @Axelrod  - the details are much different. Novelizations and other books cover this in detail.

Comment: @DVK Do you have any references you would reccomend? I'd like to improve my answer if possible.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Alternatively, you could post your own answer; I'll upvote it if it seems sound.